# Predict the number from addition of numbers

Tags: algorithm, math, data-structures

Somebody asked me this algorithmic question and as usual, I failed to answer this. :) Let us say, you have one number (call it a)

```
504
```

Next time, you see it, you delete the last digit of the number. It becomes (call it b)

```
50
```

Next time, you see it, you delete the last digit of the number. It becomes (call it c)

```
5
```

Now, add all of the three numbers(a+b+c). It becomes :

```
504 + 50 + 5 = 559
```

Alright, by now you might have understand the problem statement quite well.

Question is : Given the addition of three numbers `a + b + c` to you(in this case 559), how can you go back to the original number(in this case 504)? All solutions would be appreciated.

Comment: if a+b+c is small (<= 10^6), we can use bruteforce, try every possibility from 1 until a+b+c.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose the number you started with looks like `xyz`. That is, its last (decimal) digit is *z*, its penultimate digit is *y*, and the rest is *x*. In your example, if you started with 504, then x=5, y=0, z=4. The value of your original number is 100x+10y+z.

The number you end up with is the sum of (100x+10y+z), (10x+y), and x. This is 111x+11y+z.

Note that our constraints were that 0≤y≤9 and 0≤z≤9. Even with their largest values, we have 11y+z ≤ 11(9) + 9 < 111. So we can invert the transformation: pull out the largest multiple of 111, then pull out the largest multiple of 11 from the remaining, and then what's left.

```python
def transform(n):
    return n + (n/10) + (n/100)

def invert(m):
    [x, y, z] = [m/111, (m%111)/11, (m%111)%11]
    return 100*x + 10*y + z

assert transform(504) == 559 
assert invert(559) == 504
```

(Try the above in a Python shell. Note that this works even if x is not a single-digit number: `transform(12345)` gives 13702, and `invert(13702)` gives 12345, as expected.)

---

**Edit**: An alternative solution, based on the idea in [Paul Hankin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42198132/predict-the-number-from-addition-of-numbers/42208478#42208478) (please upvote it) of using `m*100/111` as a starting point. You can certainly use (the ceiling of) that value as a rough answer and try adding 1 and 2 to get the exact answer, but you can also precompute the "offset" needed from the rough answer.

```python
# Precomputation, to populate the "offset" dictionary
def sane_mod(a, m): return ((a % m) + m) % m
offset = {}
for y in range(10):
    for z in range(10):
        add = 10*y + 11*z
        offset[sane_mod(-add, 111)] = add

# Actual function
def invert2(m):
    rough = m * 100
    return (rough + offset[rough % 111]) / 111
assert invert2(559) == 504
```

Comment: In Python 3, you'll have to use `//` instead of `/` to get integer division.

Answer (score 1):

a+b+c is a + a//10 + a//100 (where // denotes rounding-down division). This is somewhere between a * 111/100 - 1.89 and a * 111/100. (1.89 because the maximum fraction discarded from a//10 is 0.9 and the maximum fraction discarded from a//100 is 0.99, and 1.89 = 0.9 + 0.99).

So, given a+b+c, we're looking for integer a such that:

```
a * 111/100 - 1.89 <= a + b + c <= a * 111/100
a - 2.0979 <= (a + b + c) * 100 / 111 <= a
```

Thus, let x = ceil((a + b + c) * 100 / 111), and one of x, x+1 or x+2 must be the solution.

Comment: Nice idea, +1. If instead of (n + ⌊n/10⌋+ ⌊n/100⌋) we get rid of the floors and do exact division the result is n+n/10+n/100=111n/100 (e.g. 504→504+50.4+5.04=555.44), and you bound the error introduced by the rounding-down. This is a general and powerful idea I should remember to try more often. Thinking like a real-analyst rather than a combinatorialist. :-)

Comment: Returning to thinking like a combinatorialist: when you calculate m*100/111, you're short of the correct value of n by exactly (10y+11z)/111, where *yz* are the last two digits of n, and these are all distinct for 0≤y≤9, 0≤z≤9, so you can maintain a map from the fractional part of m*100/111 to the actual value of (10y+11z)/111, to directly figure out which of x, x+1, x+2 it is, instead of trying all three.